# Why is StoragePool's OperationalStatus degraded?

Tags: windows-server-2012, storage-spaces

I have a Storage Spaces Storage Pool that has an **OperationalStatus** of `degraded`, and a **HealthStatus** of `Warning`:

```
> Get-StoragePool | Format-List *
```

> - Usage: Other
> - **OperationalStatus: Degraded**
> - **HealthStatus: Warning**
> - ProvisioningTypeDefault: Fixed
> - SupportedProvisioningTypes: {Thin, Fixed}
> - ReadOnlyReason: None
> - RetireMissingPhysicalDisks: Auto
> - ObjectId: {60e295c2-9fe7-11e2-93f1-00c0f068700e}
> - PassThroughClass:
> - PassThroughIds:
> - PassThroughNamespace:
> - PassThroughServer:
> - UniqueId: {60e295c2-9fe7-11e2-93f1-00c0f068700e}
> - AllocatedSize: 11922292342784
> - ClearOnDeallocate: False
> - EnclosureAwareDefault: False
> - FriendlyName: ContosoPool
> - IsClustered: False
> - IsPowerProtected: False
> - IsPrimordial: False
> - IsReadOnly: False
> - LogicalSectorSize: 512
> - Name:
> - OtherOperationalStatusDescription:
> - OtherUsageDescription:
> - PhysicalSectorSize: 4096
> - ResiliencySettingNameDefault: Mirror
> - Size: 14995609878528
> - SupportsDeduplication: False
> - ThinProvisioningAlertThresholds: {70}
> - PSComputerName:
> - CimClass: ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/Storage:MSFT_StoragePool
> - CimInstanceProperties: {ObjectId, PassThroughClass, PassThroughIds, PassThroughNamespace...}
> - CimSystemProperties: Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimSystemProperties

[image]

And yet none of the **virtual disks** in the pool are *degraded*:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-VirtualDisk

FriendlyName     ResiliencySettingName OperationalStatus HealthStatus IsManualAttach  Size
------------     --------------------- ----------------- ------------ --------------  ----
Three-way mirror Mirror                OK                Healthy      False          10 TB
PooledParityDisk Parity                OK                Healthy      False          15 TB
```

Rather than playing twenty-questions with Storage Spaces about why it is **Degraded**, where do i go to find a log that tells me exactly:

- **why** it's degraded
- **what** StorageSpaces is doing to fix it
- **when** it will be fixed

### Bonus Chatter

There are no **StorageJobs** running either:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-StorageJob
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

and there are no events in the Windows **Application** or **System** event logs.

Of course, those are part of the twenty-questions game that i'm not playing. I want Storage Spaces to explain itself.

**Update**: Still degraded 5 years later. Hello StorageSpaces; what is wrong.

### Bonus Reading

- MSDN: [**Get-StoragePool** commandlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/storage/get-storagepool?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) *(cmdlet is undocumented)*
- Microsoft forums: [Degraded Storage Spaces Storage Pool after single HDD failure](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3a7e2a7d-4ad7-48cc-8165-0d6673e37436/degraded-storage-spaces-storage-pool-after-single-hdd-failure?forum=winserveressentials)
- [Technet: Storage Spaces Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11382.storage-spaces-frequently-asked-questions-faq.aspx?PageIndex=2#How_do_I_check_Storage_Spaces_resiliency_health_in_a_failover_cluster)